# Why are AUC and logloss metrics not available in the "maximum metrics" table produced by H2O?

Tags: r, predictive-models, prediction, boosting, h2o

I am running the h2o.gbm algorithm using five-fold cross validation to predict a binary outcome. I want to see what threshold to use as a cutoff for classifying predictions, and I am wondering why the AUC and logloss are not shown in that table. I see F1, F0.5, F2, accuracy, etc.--but my understanding is that AUC and logloss can also be used to evaluate the performance of a binary prediction. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the allusion here is to a package, not an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The various thresholds tell you where in the [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) to use. But the AUC is Area Under Curve. So in a sense it  represents all the thresholds.

Logloss is a distinct metric from true/false negative/positive, so is not part of the ROC curve. It is weighting by the confidence in each prediction, not just if it was correct or not. (Searching the [logloss] and [auc] tags [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=AUC%20logloss) might explain the distinction better.)

Using AUC for binomial classifications, and logloss for multinomial (3+ category) classifications, is a good rule of thumb: it works well in my experience, and also ticks the "copy behaviour of people cleverer than me" box :-)